# php saving BLOB to database permissions error

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, blob

I'm trying to save some variables, an image and a pdf file to my mysql database. (using longblob for both the image and the pdf file). On doing so I get the following errors:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user
```

&

```
 Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given
```

I've checked the grant tables

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* user....
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES
```

To be honest I'm not even sure whether the code will work but I'd like to at least eliminate the errors first.  Does anyone know ho I can fix this and where i'm going wrong? any code examples greatly appreciated.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

/*** connect to db ***/
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_DATABASE, DB_PASSWORD);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $title = $_POST["title"];
            $authors = $_POST["authors"];
            $description = $_POST["description"];
            $price = $_POST["price"];
            $file = $_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file2 = $_FILES ['content']['tmp_name'];

            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

            $content = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['content']['tmp_name']));

            $sql = "INSERT INTO books2 VALUES ('$title', '$authors', '$description', '$price', 
         '$image','$content') ";
          $r = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
          if($r)
          {
         echo "<p>Thank you for entering this book!</p>";
            }


}
```

Comment: `mysql_query($sql, $conn);` you reversed the paramaters. $conn goes in first. Also why are you not using PDO? I see you're already connecting to the db using it.

Comment: I left the PDO statement in by accident as I failed to do anything with it.  I only have a very basic understanding of PHP, hence why I'm here asking for help.  But thanks for your suggestion, i will do that.

Comment: Word of advice. It's a very bad idea to save files in the database as a blob. You'd want to save the path to the file, but keep the actual file in a folder somewhere on the server.

Comment: Ok Thanks, ill  work on that instead.